# Entry in GUI and print in IDLE (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

**Hi, i have a problem with my code....I want the entry of variables and equations when clicking is shown in the IDLE....Help**

````
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('NAES Solver')
window.geometry('650x450')

#Creacion de mi funcion
def variecu():
    mensaje=src.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    print (mensaje)
    window.destroy()

    
#Entrada en horizontal 
ttk.Label(window, text = "Variables"). grid(column=0, row=0)
src = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width = 20, height = 2, wrap = tk.WORD)
src.grid(column = 7, row = 1)

#Entrada en horizontal y vertical
ttk.Label(window, text = "Ecuaciones"). grid(column = 0, row = 5)
src = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width = 20, height = 5, wrap = tk.WORD)
src.grid(column = 7, row = 7)

#Creacion del boton para imprimir la funcion
action=ttk.Button(window, text="Picale", command=variecu).grid(column=8, row=4)

window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: You've told us what you want, but you haven't asked a question. What is preventing you from doing what you want to do?

Comment: You have assigned two different `ScrolledText` widgets to the name `src`.  Both widgets will exist, and be usable - but you won't have any easy way to retrieve the contents of the first one, because you no longer have a name that refers to that widget.

Comment: @jasonharper Sureeeee, I have two data but alone i have a src in place of src1 and src2, thankss so much.  Good night